# Выборка значений из столбца в SQL таблице отфильтрованных по интервалу дат

Tags: php, java, mysql, sql

Имеется такая таблица table в PHPMyadmin:

```
user_id   test  nummer_id    finished                Date
   1       25       1            1           2015-03-11 10:11:20
   1       25       2            1           2015-03-11 10:11:22
   1       25       3            1           2015-03-11 10:12:39
   1       25       4            1           2015-03-11 10:12:45
   2       25       1            1           2015-03-15 10:12:23
   2       25       2            1           2015-03-15 10:12:33
   2       25       3            1           2015-03-15 10:12:39
   2       25       4            0           2015-03-15 10:12:55
   3       25       1            1           2015-03-21 10:12:12
   3       25       2            1           2015-03-21 10:12:23
   3       25       3            1           2015-03-21 10:12:44
   3       25       4            1           2015-03-21 10:12:52
```

В приложении на java задается интервал дат, на основании которых  нужно вывести данные из базы данных и посчитать количество в столбце user_id.

Необходимо сравнить все одинаковые значения в столбце user_id со столбцом finished. Если все эти одинаковые значения в столбце user_id равны "1" в столбце finished  то считать эти все одинаковые user_id как за единицу. Если "0" то тогда этот user_id не учитывать при подсчете.

Пример:

Интервал дат введенный пользовтелем в приложении:

```
  с 10.03.2015 по 30.03.2015.
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
  Итого кол- во участников, закончивших работу: 2
  Итого кол- во участников, не закончивших работу: 1
```

То есть первые четыре единицы равны "1" и третьи четыре тройки равны "1". Четыре двойки  пропускаем так как одна из них равна "0". Поэтому Итог: 2

C выборкрй по дате думаю можно так сделать.

```
 SELECT * FROM name_table WHERE Date BETWEEN [начальная дата] AND        
 [конечная дата]
```

Но как проверить все значения в столбце `user_id`?

Comment: Для получения проверенного ответа желательно выложить и DDL используемых таблиц, и дамп их. Я б помог, но лень в ручную формировать и заполнять таблицы.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select sum(finished) div 4, count(distinct user_id) - sum(finished) div 4 
from t;

select sum(case when a=0 then 1 else 0 end), 
sum(case when a!=0 then 1 else 0 end)
from (  
select user_id, sum(finished)-count(*) a from t
group by user_id
) X;
```

Comment: не работает так как эта не вся таблица и дальше у меня идет разное количество user_id то есть 5 четверок 7 восьмерок и т.д.

Comment: но за count(distinct user_id) спасибо полезная функция

Comment: select  count(distinct user_id) 
       from 

       table        

      where finished =1        но тогда  я не могу сравнить все одинаковые значения в user_id с finished

Comment: То есть мне сначало нужно каждый одинаковый элемент user_id сравнивать с finished и только если все эти элементы равны 1 то тогда  считать эти одинаковые элементы как за единицу.

Comment: Обновил. + еще 7 символов

Comment: спасибо огромное вроде бы все работает

Comment: Не за что.
Обращайтесь. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, если предположить что поле finished может иметь только значения 0 и 1:

```
SELECT SUM(T.finished), COUNT(T.user_id) - SUM(T.finished)
FROM
( SELECT user_id, MIN(finished) finished
  FROM name_table
  WHERE Date BETWEEN [начальная дата] AND [конечная дата]
  GROUP BY user_id ) T
```